# Can an iPhone get infected will malware by sharing a wifi connection with an infected computer?

Tags: iphone, wifi, malware

Can an iPhone Xs, not jailbroken, get infected with malware by connecting to the same Wifi network as an infected Macbook on the same apple ID account?

Comment: Is this a theoretical question or are you looking at some specific issues your iPhone has?

Comment: I’m going to put a hold on this. The answers are covering cases not even related to sharing a hotspot and going into general WiFi bugs. If there’s a specific issue, we can reopen this, but in general, the possibility of compromise over network is a “yes, it’s possible and has been discovered, reported, patched in the past”

Answer (score 3):

In theory *any* computer (including smartphones) is attackable over WiFi (or any other channel) as long as software has bugs which can be exploited to do so. Having a infected MacBook to start with, or sharing the AppleID between devices, *may* make it easier (or open additional attack vectors), but at the end it's always a weakness on the attacked device which makes it possible.

Answer (score 3):

Yes, with the emphasis on 'can'. It's not inevitable.

Answer (score 0):

**Yes**, and it's not even theoretical. In fact, the potential for this was shown (and has now been fixed with an update) by a security researcher from Google - [iPhone zero-click Wi-Fi exploit is one of the most breathtaking hacks ever](https://arstechnica.com/gadgets/2020/12/iphone-zero-click-wi-fi-exploit-is-one-of-the-most-breathtaking-hacks-ever/).